# Random, very specific kind of reboot in PC

Tags: crash, hardware-failure, reboot, pci-express, hard-drive-failure

My computer is rendered unusable due to immediate restarts after booting up.  Sometimes it is within seconds, and sometimes within minutes. On a new day (after 8-9 hours) it runs well for a few hours, but then the problem repeats itself.

It happens in Ubuntu, Windows 7, and Windows 10, so it is not a software problem.

It never happens on BIOS, which I think is very strange.

The computer case used to give very mild shocks. So I called in an electrician and checked the earthing.  It was fine.  I dissembled the computer and ran through only 1 memory stick and the bare essentials.  But I still had to use the GPU because my TV uses only HDMI.  The problem did not go away.

So, what can be the problem? Is it a faulty SSD from where I boot up?

My specs are as follows-
Gigabyte h81 ms1 motherboard 
Pentium G3240
Zotac 750Ti
Corsair VS450
1TB HDD
128 GB SanDisk SSD(Bootable media)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you think this has anythiong to do with PCI-express ? Or why with the harddrive?

Comment: I cannot run my Pc without the PCI express card,  because I use a TV as the monitor.  And I wonder if this is a hard drive malfunctioning symptom. As it is fine in Bios but not in OS.

Comment: Sounds like a PSU problem if you ask me

Comment: But then why is it very stable in the Bios and immediately restarting once an OS is loaded?  Is there any tool I can use to check the PSU?  Or must I obtain another one and check? (BTW I specifically bought a branded PSU fearing failure which is many times costlier than cheap ones)

Comment: While in the BIOS, there won't be anywhere near the constant strain on the PSU, as most of the system isn't in use/stressed while in the BIOS (drives, etc.). If you want to test the PSU theory then yeah you'll need another, known-good PSU to test with.